# Is this have any affect on why my BIND9 is not working?

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, unix, bind

```
$/etc/init.d/bind9 restart
Stopping domain name service...: bind9rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
.
Starting domain name service...: bind9.
```

(By the way, this is a continuation of the question here: [Can someone see why my DNS won't work? I followed everything in the tutorial, but won't work](https://serverfault.com/questions/82127/can-someone-see-why-my-dns-wont-work-i-followed-everything-in-the-tutorial-bu))

Comment: There is insufficient information here to be able to take a reasonable stab at an answer, and you've been given guidance on what information to provide in your previous question, which should have been extended rather than asking another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure **Bind** and **rndc** if you want that **rndc** talk to **Bind**.

You should have something like that in your **named.conf**:

```
controls {
  inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { <key-name>; };
};

...

key "<key-name>" {
  algorithm hmac-md5;
  secret "<key-value>";
};
```

and something like that in your **rndc.conf**:

```
options {
  default-server  localhost;
  default-key     "<key-name>";
};

...

key "<key-name>" {
  algorithm hmac-md5;
  secret "<key-value>";
};
```

But you should read named.conf and rndc.conf manuals first ! :)

```
man named.conf
man rndc.conf
```

Comment: +1 for "But you should read named.conf and rndc.conf manuals first". :)

Answer (score 1):

> `#953` is the rndc socket for controlling bind. the restart is giving you an error because it tried to connect to the socket and couldn't,
>   probably because bind wasn't actually running.

After the startup script is finished running, does `ps auxww` show a 'named' process running? if so, and restart doesn't work, check your rndc key setup. If named isn't starting at all, look in the logs for why.

based on your other question you should do some reading before attempting to run dns. I recommend the cricket liu "DNS & Bind" O'Reilley book.

Comment: Yes, it is running. bind     16922  0.0  6.8 215020 22452 ?        Ssl  09:49   0:00 /usr/sbin/named -u bind